# Is there an OCaml function for determining if every element of an integer list is in sequential order?

Tags: list, ocaml, sequential

For example, I would want to return true with the list
[1;2;3;4], but not [1;3;4;5].

I have tried this so far. I believe that this works based on my test cases so far... but If anyone has feedback or advice that would be great. Basically, I am unsure of how to implement it using the built-in list library that I know run more efficiently than hard-coded efforts. Could this be implemented with fold_left or fold_right?

```
let is_seq elt1 elt2 =
  if elt2 - elt1 = 1 then true else false

let next_elem lst = 
  match lst with 
  | [] -> failwith "this should not happen"
  | h :: t -> h

(**[is_sequential lst] returns true if the list is sequential and 
   false if it is not *)
let rec is_sequential lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> true
  | h :: [] -> true
  | h :: t -> if is_seq h (next_elem t) then is_sequential t else false
```

Comment: You have not mentioned what you have tried so far. Let us know specifics of what you tried, why it didn't work, etc.

Comment: If this implementation gives the correct answer but you're not sure about best practices, then I recommend posting on the Code Review Stack Exchange to ask for advice: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are handling int overflow..

```
let rec is_seq lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> true
  | hd::[] -> true
  | hd1::hd2::tl when hd1 = Int.max_int -> failwith "Int too large to continue"
  | hd1::hd2::tl when (succ hd1) = hd2 -> is_sorted (hd2::tl)
  | _ -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

So my suggestion for a fold_left would be to have an accumulator that contains the previously met integer:

```
let is_sequential l = 
  match l with 
  | [] -> true 
  | x::xs -> 
     List.fold_left (fun (is_seq,prev_e) e -> (e = prev_x + 1 && is_seq,e)) (true,x) xs
```

You might also use exceptions to stop whenever is_seq becomes false...